# Writing gibberish to a file?

Tags: c, printf

So I'm opening a file, lets call that file key.txt

```
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("key.txt", "r");
```

Now lets say I have another file (fa) that I opened with code "a" to append to it. Now im reading all of the characters from fp and appending each alphabetical character to the file fp, but it's appending MORE than that.

```
    char c;
    do {
        c = getc(fp);
        if(isalpha(c)){
            fprintf(fa, &c);
            fprintf(fa, "\n");
        }
     } while(c != EOF);
```

Ok so this looks good to me, now it is adding each alphabetical character to the file, but the issue is, it's added even **MORE** characters to a single line of text. I'm trying to pinpoint this issue.
Here is an example, inside key.txt we have

```
    lol
    xd
```

The output file fa has the contents

```
    l<82>^0)y^?
    o<82>^0)y^?
    l<82>^0)y^?
    x<82>^0)y^?
    d<82>^0)y^?
```

So im not getting what's going on here. How do I fix this? Im not sure what the exact issue is

Comment: `fprintf(fa, &c);` --> `fprintf(fa, "%c", c);`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh that worked thank you! Craig Estey, I did compile with -Wall and it was working just fine

Comment: Yes, it does compile [I double checked after looking again], which is why I deleted my first comment. The `&c` [technically speaking] would be a `char *` and would be accepted by the format scanner in the compiler. It wouldn't be able to deduce that it wasn't the equivalent of `char fmt[2]` and flag it

Comment: when calling `fprintf()`  pass the contents of the parameters, not the address of the parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `fprintf()` wrong. From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf), the expected format is

```
int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
```

where, the first argument is the file pointer, the second one is the conversion specifier and third one onwards is (are) the argument(s) to the conversion specifier mentioned.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, `fprintf()`, for the format specifier

> `c`
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the `int` argument is converted to an
> `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written. [...]

So, in case, you want to write a character, you need to use something like

```
fprintf(fa, "%c", c);   //%c for character, no '&' needed before variable
```

That said, `getc()` returns an `int` so you should capture the return value in an `int` variable.

*Moral of the story:* Enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fragment has several problems:

```
char c;
do {
    c = getc(fp);
    if(isalpha(c)){
        fprintf(fa, &c);
        fprintf(fa, "\n");
    }
 } while(c != EOF);
```

- `c` should be declared with the `int` type to accommodate for all values of type `unsigned char` plus the special negative value `EOF`.
- `fprintf` must be passed a format string. `fprintf(fa, &c);` has undefined behavior.  Use `fprintf(fa, "%c", c);` or simply `putc(c, fa);`. *undefined behavior* means anything can happen: gibberish output is one possibility, a program crash is another...
- check for `EOF` before further processing in the loop.  The `do { ... } while` loop is not appropriate, use `while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) { ... }` instead.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int c;
while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if (isalpha(c)) {
        fprintf(fa, "%c\n", c);
    }
 }
```